# Can I reach performance if I encapsulate a parameter of a recursive function?

Tags: java, performance, recursion, jvm, encapsulation

I have a function that sorts a given array using the merge sort algorithm. That algorithm calls itself to solve the problem.

```
public class MergeSort {
    
    public static void mergeSort(int[][] arr, int left, int right) {
        // merge two parts
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
        
        // sort the left part
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        // sort the right part
        mergeSort(arr, mid, right);
    }   
}
```

Can I reach performance if I encapsulate the `arr` parameter in the class? Consider:

```
public class MergeSort {
    int[][] arr;
    
    public void mergeSort(int left, int right) {
        // merge two parts
        merge(left, mid, right);
        
        // sort the left part
        mergeSort(left, mid);
        // sort the right part
        mergeSort(mid, right);
    }
}
```

So, the `arr` parameter is not passing to the stack.

Comment: Arrays are - in general - allocated on the heap, not on the stack. The only thing that will be on the stack in your first code is the reference to the array of `arr`, not the array itself. The fact you pass the reference to the array as a parameter might actually be better for performance than using a field. Also, making this a field could introduce all kinds of issues if you don't use instances of `MergeSort` correctly.

Comment: yes, it will be better than pass it on the stack with every call.

Comment: @Khanna111 That is unlikely.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see. So if the arr is a local variable defined in the method itself, it would still be in the heap and only a reference would be passed?

Comment: The array is on the heap, `arr` is just a reference to that array. And although each method invocation may add yet another reference to that same array on the stack, that is trivial (and possibly this might be optimized away).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Rotteveel yes, but it is a reference. It takes memory.

Comment: @Arkady Those four bytes are nothing, and the locality of the reference on the stack may make it faster than having to access the field of the instance.

Comment: If you want to be sure though, consider writing a JMH test, see also [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel then the parameter will be removed from the stack and placed again. But the class field will stand still until the end

Comment: Yes, but the method needs to access the field on each use, which is generally more expensive than accessing a local variable on the stack.

Comment: Perhaps, you should first *implement an actual working* version of MergeSort, before asking about the performance of a tiny detail, that becomes irrelevant anyway, given how mergesort works.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel tell me please, how is field accessing implemented. When we are creating an object the field data is initializing to the local stack. What prevents a function from fast accessing a class field as its parameter on the stack?

Comment: André LaMothe says in his book that to make calling a function fast, you can use global variables as method parameters. The book is very old.

Comment: @Holger it's not about the sorting algorithm. I am trying to understand how can I make function calls faster.

Comment: Well, then you should probably implement *anything* working, before worrying about the performance of the thing with the least impact on the overall performance. If you have something real, you can ask whether there are opportunities to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

variables reserve a reference to use from ram. It doesn't matter where you define it, if you're using 1 byte of ram it's the same everywhere.

The important thing is that if the developer wants to use this variable in the program, he can use it easily and separate it from other variables.

If you say why parameters are used, it is necessary to understand why functions are used. The simplest functions are to separate the codes you wrote from other codes and to access these codes easily. That's why the parameters exist.